# Having unique values by keys in a dict

Tags: python, dictionary, collections

For each keys in my dict I would like to have unique values : 
My current implementation :

```
from collections import defaultdict

a = ["key1", "key2"]
b = ["value1", "value2", "value2", "value3"]

d = defaultdict(list)
for key in a:
    for value in b:
        d[key].append(value)
```

The current result is :

```
{'key1': ["value1", "value2", "value2", "value3"] , 'key2': ["value1", "value2", "value2", "value3"]}
```

but I would like (even in disorder) :

```
{'key1': ["value1", "value2", "value3"], 'key2': ["value1", "value2", "value3"]}
```

(where the values for each keys are unique)

Comment: I find that very hard to believe: `b` as shown is a `set`, so won't hold duplicate values. I cannot recreate your claimed output, I get `defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'key2': ['value3', 'value2', 'value1'], 'key1': ['value3', 'value2', 'value1']})` for `d`, which is **already what you say you want**.

Comment: I've edited your samples into shape, but you have to clarify your question. Your syntax use is entirely incorrect, and confusing. You probably meant `a` and `b` to be **lists**, not sets, for example.

Comment: @Hackaholic: please don't add comments about checking your answer. The OP is *already notified* of your answer, we can all see it just fine. Your comment can be seen as attention spamming, please don't do that.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters : sorry, the real context is pretty complicated so I've tried to summarize in a short example which didn't work at all. Thus, I've edited the first post which should now work.

Comment: I think I get the solution thanks to your answers :
    d = defaultdict(set)    
    for key in a:    
        for value in b:    
            d[key].add(value)    

With this, it works just fine

Comment: @user3278877: does order matter at all here? E.g. is `{key1: ["value2", "value3", "value1"], ...}` acceptable too?

Comment: @user3278877: ah, I think that you already stated that; presumably that is what you meant by *disorder*. In which case `sweeneyrod`'s answer has you covered.

Comment: @MartijnPieters the order does not matter. This result is acceptable. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a set for the dictionary values:

```
d = defaultdict(set)
for key in a:
    for value in b:
        d[key].add(value)
```

Note that this will require the values to be hashable.